# Paypal TLS 1.2 and .NET 3.5 Compatibility

Tags: api, http, ssl, paypal

Our site is version .NET 3.5 which means that it does not support TLS 1.2. Is there any other way to implement TLS 1.2 other than to upgrade to .NET 4.5?

Upgrading to 4.5 is the best solution however this would be a huge project and require lots of resources that we simply cannot get done before June 2017.

Comment: Sorry, but .NET 3.5 was released in 2007. It's really **very old**. At least 2010 you should planned upgrading to more recent version of .NET. If you really can't upgrade now then you should install one additional server with .NET 4.6, which you would use to communicate with PayPal. I strictly recommend you to plan migration to ASP.NET Core in the next time independent from the problem with TLS 1.2. Additionally I'd recommend you to test your web site in https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. It could be that it have really heavy security problems because of usage old technologies.

Comment: Yes. I inherited the project :) . we did upgrade to 4.0 so we are working fine against the upgraded paypal sandbox apis. no problem there. until jun3 17th 2016, i.e. 5 days from now, can we deploy the latest paypal SDK and will it work with current PROD api's? (backward compatible). Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

If Windows Server 2008 R2, you'll need .NET 3.5.1 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3154518)

I believe the following will tell .NET to use the versions allowed by SCHANNEL (I think this is preferred):
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

Otherwise, another way for TLS 1.1 and 1.2:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

You'll need also need to tell the OS to enable Tls 1.2 in SCHANNEL which take the form:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000 "Enabled"=dword:00000001 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server] "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000 "Enabled"=dword:00000001

Additional info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/07/12/enable-tls-1-2-protocol-for-reporting-services-with-custom-net-application/